# Pull container from dockerhub

Tags: docker, .net-framework, core

Hi I am new on docker and I created a default .net core web mvc application with docker for linux from my windows 10 machine.It was running and push it to dockerhub.From my ubuntu 16.04 32bit (i386) machine I pulled the image and stat running it.I got the following mesage: standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"
Any suggestion how to resolve it?

Comment: You probably used a 64-bit base image. 32-bit x86 computing is all but dead these days.

Comment: Can I do something with the architecture to make it run on docker on ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You can run 32bit code on a 64bit machine, but not the other way around. Either find a 32bit docker image for your purpose, or upgrade your linux to 64bit to enjoy both worlds.

Check this link for more info https://forums.docker.com/t/support-for-32-bit-images-containers-on-64-bit-hosts/10010

In particular this answer https://forums.docker.com/t/support-for-32-bit-images-containers-on-64-bit-hosts/10010/5